# "feint toward" or "feint to", "to" vs "toward"

Tags: prepositions, compounds

Consider:

> They were duped by Allies feint to the south leaving the way open for Normandy invasion.
>
> They were duped by Allies feint toward the south leaving the way open for Normandy invasion.

I have two questions:

1. Which one of them is correct?

(I searched in Google. Both of "feint toward" and "feint to" are common.)

2. If both of the sentences are correct, in general, are the prepositions "toward" and "to" interchangeable?

Comment: Are these your examples or can you add a source? Maybe it is me (AmE) but I have never heard "feint" beyond literary usage.

Comment: Yes of course, see :
https://books.google.com/books?id=7M-V0cqNMHAC&pg=PA50&lpg=PA50&dq=1100+words+you+need+to+know+feint&source=bl&ots=_BOCdQzkK7&sig=mWE-MiPhG5zAyhgRwl0dx7RBnB8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CCQQ6AEwAmoVChMIqtT1t52nxwIVQjgUCh3wBwAo#v=onepage&q=1100%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know%20feint&f=false

Comment: You can also google those terms

Comment: I hear feint all the time in ordinary conversation.  (but I do spend a lot of time in fencing clubs...)

Answer (score 1):

'To' describes (changed) location, whereas 'toward' indicates direction.  You reach towards the sky, but you put your knuckle to your brow.

In the contexts of feints, the suggestion of a feint TO a target would probably be a weak attack, or at least forces in position.  A feint TOWARD a target would be a movement of forces toward a location suggesting an attack was planned there.